Django upload file to Dropbox
Is there any way to upload file from Django to Dropbox as code below for your reference:
Created one folder in root directory than copy all files from root directory to dropbox.
TOKEN = "xxxxxxx"

LOCALFILE = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'dcfiles')

BACKUPPATH = "/Apps/backup/"# Keep the forward slash before destination filename

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(TOKEN)

dbx.files_upload(LOCALFILE, BACKUPPATH)

Error:
Internal Server Error: /app01/strequest/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/test2/app01/views.py", line 35, in strequest
    dbx.files_upload(LOCALFILE, BACKUPPATH)
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 3214, in files_upload
    r = self.request(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 326, in request
    res = self.request_json_string_with_retry(host,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 476, in request_json_string_with_retry
    return self.request_json_string(host,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/imac/Desktop/Project/Test2/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 538, in request_json_string
    raise TypeError('expected request_binary as binary type, got %s' %
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'str'>

